# What do i have to do to create a local domain for my wordpress instance in xampp within accessing it for any device (exsiting wordpress project)

Tags: wordpress, xampp

I have an existing project in wordpress combined with a database on MySQL and ive actually started this project with the newest version of wordpress (wordpress.org) and xampp

At the beginning i was working with the default Settings of xampp like:
- localhost domain only local available (Apache)

After the first steps of coding on wordpress i just asked myself if i could change my 'localhost' domain to something like 'www.example.com' and access this domain for my home network even via wifi to easily show up my work changes on any device at home

ive been searching for a way to create a local network domain
-> This step worked

Actually i could type in the domain ive already changed and then i was able to get my web project on wordpress

## Virtual Hosts Configuration Apache File

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/example.com"
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
ErrorLog "logs/example.com-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

## Hosts File from Windows

```
127.0.0.1 www.example.com
```

After those step i still kept on struggling how to make it work for my phone or the laptop of my dad just to get the real website imagination

Because even i changed some details it only worked for another device if ive called the index.php in my dev-folder but it was only displayed as RAW HTML

I really hope you could help me with that thanks for paying attention

Kind regards
NateDev

Comment: You can use https://ngrok.com/ software it will easily create live url. After creating live url you can change in your wordpress. Even this software help to share your url to anyone but one condition you not close your pc.

Comment: Thanks Jinesh i try that one :)

Comment: is it working or not?

Comment: Hi Jinesh ive seen the link and i already install the ngrok on my notebook but on the website it says that in the free version it always generate a random url but the thing is i would like to set my own url to use it in my network

Comment: is there any other way to do the same for free?

Comment: You have to purchase this software then I think they can support you